# How to write a map statement to compare each elements of two lists in haskell?

Tags: haskell, compiler-errors

I have two functions both of which return a list:

```
enter earth = head $ do
  lst <- earth
  return $ map (\x -> if (x == 0) then 2 else x) lst

helper earth = head $ do
  lst <- tail (earth)
  return lst
```

where earth is another function that returns a list of lists like [[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[4,7,3]]. In the helper function, I am returning the second element of this list of lists, i.e., the head of the tail. And in the enter function, only the head. Now I am writing another function and I want to pass these two functions as arguments to it. I'm doing this:

```
see :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]
see enter helper = return $ map (\ x y -> if (x == 2) && (y == 0) then 2 else y) enter helper
```

I'm basically trying to do is to check if the list returned by enter has a 2 and the second list has a zero at that location, then change that 0 to 2 otherwise let the element in the second list be as it is.

What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT:

So, there is an earth function returning like this: [[0,0,1],[1,0,1],[0,0,0]]. The enter function, takes the head of earth(which is [0,0,1] and makes it like this: [2,2,1]. The helper function takes and returns the second element (the head of the tail) of the list of lists returned by earth (which is [1,0,1]). Now the see function, takes these [2,2,1] and [1,0,1] as two arguments, and if an element is 2 in the first list and 0 in the second list (i.e., from this example, the second element in both lists, then that 0 should become 2 in the second list, and what should be returned should be something like this: [1,2,1]

Comment: Use some `zip` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want something like this:

```
       xs = [ ...,     1,     2,     0,     1, ... ]
       ys = [ ...,     3,     0,     4,     0, ... ]
zip xs ys = [ ..., (1,3), (2,0), (0,4), (1,0), ... ]
   result = [ ...,     3,     2,     4,     0, ... ]
```

`result` is the list `ys` with the zeros replaced with 2s where there is a 2 in the list `xs`.

So you can express this logic pretty much directly as a list comprehension:

```
result = [ r | (x,y) <- zip xs ys, let r = if y == 0 && x == 2 then 2 else y ]
```

Comment: So, now I'm writing something like this: see = [ r | (x,y) <- zip enter helper, let r = if y == 0 && x == 2 then 2 else y ] But I'm getting a type error.

Comment: `enter` and `helper` are functions, not lists. If `as` is a list, then `enter as` is also a list, so you want to replace `xs` with `enter as` and `ys` with `helper bs` for some list expressions `as` and `bs`

Comment: I worked that out. Could you tell me if I can write some kind of nested if statements inside a list comprehension? Like the list that result returned, I want to do some computation on each element of that list. Is this possible to write nested if inside this list comprehension?

Comment: There are a lot of ways to do it, but how about just `map f result` where `f` is the function you want to apply to each element of `result`? Sounds like a good candidate for a new SO question.

Answer (score 2):

[`zipWith`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v:zipWith) is the function that you're looking for. `map` only works on one list at a time, so your usage of it will result in a type error. If you just replace `map` with `zipWith` in that last line, it should work. Also, you should remove the `return`. In the context of a list, `return` only puts something into a singleton list: `return x = [x]`. Note that `return` is a function and is not really related to the `return` in C-influenced languages. I would also suggest not using `do` notation for lists at this point.

Also, the last function isn't using the other two functions, even though it uses those names. I'm not sure if this is what you want or not though. It is equivalent to a definition of `see` where you used the names `x` and `y` instead of `enter` and `helper`.

Here's an example of the behavior of `zipWith`:

```
λ> zipWith (*) [2, 3, 4] [10, 100, 1000]
[20,300,4000]
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that my last function doesn't need enter and helper function. It is getting the two lists from those functions only, on which it will perform computations. :O

Comment: @EricaMaine Oh, I was just saying that those arguments don't need to have the same name as those other functions, but it will work either way. By the other part, I mean instead of using `map` in the `see` function, you want to use `zipWith`. `zipWith` has the behavior you describe of applying a two argument function across two lists in the way that you want (see the documentation link luqui added to my answer for reference).

Comment: @EricaMaine I added a demonstration of how `zipWith` works. Also, it looks like there's a terminological problem: `earth` is a list, not a function (not something I was expecting to say today, haha).

Answer (score 1):

`map` only walks over 1 list, but you try to walk over 2 lists at the same time, and calculate something.

So you need a function which takes a function with 2 parameters, 2 lists and returns a list with the same type of the result of the function: [`(a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]`](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%28a-%3Eb-%3Ec%29+-%3E+[a]+-%3E+[b]+-%3E+[c])

And hoogle finds a function which has this property: [`zipWith`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:zipWith)

So you write a helper function which does what you want:

```
helper 0 2 = 2
helper _ y = y
```

now you write the see function and put the helper function in a where clause (you probably don't need that function later):

```
see a b = zipWith helper a b
    where helper 2 0 = 2
          helper _ y = y
```

I don't know why you use `do` but this is not necessary here.